# What is Design Element in the context of asset management

Tags: cad, construction-management

In the context of physical asset management (BIM etc) what is a Design Element? I have come across the term several time but never in an official document - can anyone explain the term and provide a definition in case it is an actual professional term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia explains the term "Design Element" quite well. I don't expect there is a formal "official definition" of the term Design Element, but the relevance to BIM (Building Information Modelling) seems fairly obvious.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_design_elements_and_principles
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_design#Experiential_graphic_design